# Loading feature data into Vega-Lite

Tags: javascript, r, json, vega-lite, jsonlite

I'm trying to plot area shapes using vega-lite but the following area is being reported.

[Warning] Dropping {"type":"geojson"} from channel "shape" since it does not contain any data field, datum, value, or signal.

The data is being successfully loaded as I can see it the vega-lite editor/ viewer and it I've included a couple of records below and in the link to the [vega-lite snippet](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5QECJAroxrZLGxgA2hsNgD9w5ADyAIQBSAUQDCAFQBJABErABYANgBOAEZ1J2cAdSCAJmifEJxILwAGaWzoguiADjU7J0gk1IA5AFkrSABBeG54AGtYMABxACdkZBU4+KhK6NqE+qhB+Mg3Ks6AfS8w6OTc5Kny2YWqq2SivYBmbI37SAAZFzmrEWi6fdDYstOzhr8raWS6UNCDg5PnADKAAkGgAFLzzM79agsKzZOjZSLJUL-IzAsEQhq9PRgeHZfHSVFQajIbioZB4boATysjiGUDwVMIyHqNVYYjwjFB3DEVOoylK9KMzW43U0jCUOgsVlsQsMsrl8qeiusNzuiL+YA+X1C0lCAF0ifTVbcitEAOya7U-ZGG5Vyk13ZLSK2fULJSIHO2KpyOooHSKqLVug4Pb0++Vq-3SQnBr4HfbhiM2KMHWJx77+pMRv2h2PWj7JbM+v3IoMF83RYsqqPRAPlt1683Vh1RjUNnV6-X2obdn19oUD+IAX2Vw-+dPK7m8-mCYSi6x7FRSaQyUByeUK0UigqGy+qdUyDTEYn6HR83W4sEsRP3oxq40ykyXW0WYXyET+L7m8x2OGS5qRC6RS3hcVw4GqkSAYGS4vG8ODWnWIFLui4KQtCsI4HiQEwfSkCoZi2Jwgi+KLnhJJkhS1K0j2RiMsyrLspy3K8vyAy0VAIpihKUqWDgCoOhx9gCTmkHhMUHbuisLZCo6UEWpJ0ThF6RpDHJ5rSCBGbZIBMnGpB0aSYi0h6WpkFQVp1qIs2qnxHJRThIp4Q2UJvqQRpkmrCZtlubckRFDpnmhC5yYQOpeqeeERSmXZYmAZ50QGj5wliRJGapEWrkQEOg4cTl9ijiOZTZpAABmooYHgtKQPRLKZAoAqFWA44aJAGDdK09QUbAiDoAxgyQP0zTiko1DVT1fV1Q4NVMlNkAUQ1KjDi1RgAO6MJomFaviA0oIw1D4O8+IgMOQA).

I think the trouble is pointing the right fields in the data.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "OBJECTID": 4691,
        "WD21CD": "E05011118",
        "WD21NM": "Acocks Green",
        "WD21NMW": " ",
        "BNG_E": 412052,
        "BNG_N": 282830,
        "LONG": -1.8241,
        "LAT": 52.4433,
        "SHAPE_Length": 0.0924,
        "SHAPE_Area": 0.0005,
        "geometry": {
          "type": "MultiPolygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                [-1.8093, 52.4454],
                [-1.8173, 52.4324],
                [-1.8253, 52.4293],
                [-1.839, 52.4341],
                [-1.8355, 52.4382],
                [-1.831, 52.4483],
                [-1.8345, 52.4522],
                [-1.824, 52.4571],
                [-1.8139, 52.4547],
                [-1.8093, 52.4454]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "OBJECTID": 4692,
        "WD21CD": "E05011119",
        "WD21NM": "Allens Cross",
        "WD21NMW": " ",
        "BNG_E": 401463,
        "BNG_N": 279538,
        "LONG": -1.9799,
        "LAT": 52.4138,
        "SHAPE_Length": 0.0959,
        "SHAPE_Area": 0.0002,
        "geometry": {
          "type": "MultiPolygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                [-1.9618, 52.4212],
                [-1.9717, 52.4163],
                [-1.9758, 52.4079],
                [-1.9835, 52.4095],
                [-1.9978, 52.4097],
                [-1.986, 52.4167],
                [-1.975, 52.4205],
                [-1.9807, 52.4247],
                [-1.9754, 52.4268],
                [-1.9679, 52.4214],
                [-1.9618, 52.4212]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "format": {"type": "json"}
  },
  "mark": "geoshape",
  "encoding": {"shape": {"type": "geojson"}},
  "width": 500,
  "height": 500
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my json was not formed correctly.  I had used jsonlite::toJSON in R to convert an Simple Feature to json but should have used geojsonsf::sf_geojson().  The former only includes the contents of the feature.properties.

For more info, see [Convert data to Json with all objects included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71278624/convert-data-to-json-with-all-objects-included)

The correct code is as follows, note the data definition, where the FeatureCollection and features are defined.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "OBJECTID": 4691,
            "WD21CD": "E05011118",
            "WD21NM": "Acocks Green",
            "BNG_E": 412052,
            "BNG_N": 282830,
            "LONG": -1.82411,
            "LAT": 52.443321,
            "SHAPE_Length": 0.09237554909129655,
            "SHAPE_Area": 0.000522111171395259
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  [-1.809263305999934, 52.44539377400008],
                  [-1.817314732999932, 52.43236735700003],
                  [-1.825263312999937, 52.42930558300003],
                  [-1.839003390999949, 52.434050100000036],
                  [-1.809263305999934, 52.44539377400008]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "OBJECTID": 4692,
            "WD21CD": "E05011119",
            "WD21NM": "Allens Cross",
            "WD21NMW": " ",
            "BNG_E": 401463,
            "BNG_N": 279538,
            "LONG": -1.97991,
            "LAT": 52.413849,
            "SHAPE_Length": 0.09592937334184568,
            "SHAPE_Area": 0.00023886389782556888
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  [-1.961811859999955, 52.42117633300006],
                  [-1.971725540999955, 52.41631029900003],
                  [-1.975847800999929, 52.40792152500006],
                  [-1.983516194999936, 52.409539153000026],
                  [-1.967944932999956, 52.42144882300005],
                  [-1.961811859999955, 52.42117633300006]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "format": {"type": "json", "property": "features"}
  },
  "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "strokeWidth": "1", "stroke": "White"},
  "encoding": {
    "tooltip": {"field": "properties.WD21NM"},
    "shape": {"type": "geojson"}
  },
  "width": 500,
  "height": 500
}
```